# Adding/removing filter from another filter in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying add/remove Wordpress search filter according to the page author of the page I'm currently on. The search bar is in the theme header and therefore independent of the page I am on. I would like to use the author ID of the current page to add a filter for the next search I would do in the search bar.

This is an e-commerce site. The search bar is in the header (independent of the page). I'm on the shop page. I'd like to search products (i.e. posts with the same author ID) related to the shop page I was on before the search action.

I have written the code for functions.php however it doesn't work, i.e "my_search_filter" is not added (nor deleted). What I'm missing?

```
function search_filter_by_page_author()
{
    $author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
    
    #echo $author_id;

    if (in_array($author_id, array("1", "2"))
    {       
        add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_search_filter' );      
    }
    else
    {
        remove_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_search_filter' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'search_filter_by_page_author' );

function my_search_filter( $query )
{
    if ( $query->is_search && !is_admin())
    {
        $query->set( 'author', '1, 2' );
    }   
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be very helpful if you could be a bit more specific about the "it doesn't work part". What is happening and how is this different from the expected behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. By "doesn't work" I meant that "my_search_filter" is not added. Fixed the question as you recommended...

Comment: Not sure why you are using two functions for this, when you don't need `search_filter_by_page_author()` at all. Why don't you use `add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'my_search_filter')` and handle the conditionals there?

Comment: @disinfor, Unfortunately I can't. The search query is independent of a page therefore I don't have a page author ID inside the "my_search_filter" function

Comment: How can you get the author ID before you get the post?

Comment: @mraxn I think you need to define what you are actually trying to do. I think you might be going about this the wrong way. You are trying to conditionally use `add_filter` and `remove_filter`, but the state of the filter might not be persisting.

Comment: @Howard, the flow is as follows... I'm on the particular post. Next, I do search. I would like the search be customized according to the page I was before that.

Comment: So really, you just want a link to the author archive for the page you're on?  Or is it something else?  If it's something else... please explain further.

Comment: @HowardE, No, this is an e-commerce site. The search bar is in the header (independent of the page). I'm on the shop page. I'd like to search products related to the shop page I was before the search action.

Comment: What your asking for seems a better fit for using something like FacetWP to filter the products on the current shop page, or you could have a query string in your URL with the the author id. What you have currently won't work, because your functions run on every page - so, as soon as you search, the author ID no longer exists on the search results - since `remove_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_search_filter' );` is what will always run.

Comment: _The search bar is in the header (independent of the page)._ This is also incorrect. Just because the search bar is in the header, does not make it independent from the page. The search is still subject to the data available on whatever page you are on - since the header is called on whatever page you are on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that may be what you're after.  In my opinion, you should

1. Set a new searchform.php
2. Add your `pre_get_posts` (which by the way is an action, and not a filter)

searchform.php (example) - This goes in your theme or child theme root folder.

```php
<?php 

global $post;
$author_id = $post->post_author;?>

<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" role="search" class="searchform search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="s" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_search_query() ); ?>" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search &hellip;', 'text_domain' ); ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="author" value="<?php echo $author_id;?>">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

Search filter (put in functions.php)

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'search_filter_by_page_author');
function search_filter_by_page_author($query){
  
  if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() && isset($_GET['author'])) {
    $query->set('author', $_GET['author']);
  }
  return $query;
}
```

This may not do exactly what you're looking for, but I think you should be able to get a positive result from this as a starting point.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's what I'm looking for. I think may the right answer would be why the `add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_search_filter' );` didn't add the filter. I assume it's something about function scoping...

Comment: `pre_get_posts` isn't a filter.